# Why does this Java word scrambler keep returning an error?

Tags: java, debugging

The error this word scrambler program gives back in the UNIX terminal after compiling and running as 'java' is

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0"

This is even after researching how to use "FileInputStream(args[0]))" and after constant debugging in 'jbd'

What this program is supposed to do is take a random word from a text file and then scramble it.

The text file "list.txt" reads exactly like this:

```
5
Apple
Pie
Horse
Computer
Tree
```

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class AnagramGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Random rand = new Random(1234);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));

        int size = in.nextInt();
        int selection = rand.nextInt(size);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < selection) {
            in.next();
            i++;
        }
        String word = in.next();

        StringBuffer scrambled = scramble(word, rand);
        System.out.println(scrambled);
    }

        while(sbuf.length() > 0) {
            int next = rand.nextInt(sbuf.length());
            result.append(sbuf.charAt(next));
            sbuf.deleteCharAt(next);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

[EDIT]: Coincidentally, I looked at the above link showing how to prevent such an error. The difference between this post and the other one is that this one scans directly from a text file (the first item is the number of words in the file) while the other one uses an array within the JAVA file. Sorry for this confusion.

Comment: What do you think `args[0]` should evaluate to? Why do you think so?

Comment: Show us the command line you enter to run the program from the console.

Comment: There is no args[0]. (And if you are a Ghostbusters aficionado:) "There is only Zool"

Comment: I enter "javac scrambler.java" and then it gives the error when I say "java scrambler"

Comment: So why do you expect `args[0]` not to fail?

Comment: I thought that args[0] would command to scan the document at the first number in the array. What would be an alternative then?

Comment: Which document? That array is empty.

Comment: You probably need to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) to understand how to pass arguments to a java program.

Comment: Oops, I meant text file instead of "document" or array. I'm trying to say I thought the program would read from the file, look at the first item 0 ("5"), and then interpret it as assigned to variable "i."

Comment: Again, what text file?

Comment: The one containing 5;Apple;Pie;Horse;Computer;Tree.

Comment: How is your Java program related to that file in any way? Why should it know how to locate it? Does your file have a name? Are you passing that name to your java program in any way?

Comment: My file's name is "list.txt." I think it's supposed to scan via "FileInputStream"

Comment: You're running `java scrambler`. How is that program supposed to guess at something called `list.txt`?

Comment: Oh, so in the terminal emulator I just mention the text file along with the Java file? How do I do that?

Comment: `java scrambler <argument list>`. Please read the official tutorial I linked to earlier.

Comment: Read it already and the other link. Program works now. Thanks!